# Retrieve data from sub subcollection

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to take attendance data from every `employee`. I've managed to get all the user data, but I'm confused how to get the presence data in it. Can any of you be able to help me?

- *Employee Collection Screenshot :*

[image: Employee Collection]

---

- *Presence Collection Screenshot:*
  [image: Presence Collection]

---

- *Get all user from employee collection Screenshot:*
  [image: Get all user from employee collection]

---

- *Get all user code Screenshot:*
  [image: Get all user code]

---